# Cookie issue on same server with different domain

Tags: php, cookies, session-management

I am using Zend framework 2 for my two applications (xyz.com and pqr.com) on the same server.

I have a problem with cookie, when I logged in into xyz.com and edit the browser cookie settings using Firebug from xyz.com to pqr.com then it will allow me the admin access for pqr.com.

So is there any way to solve this kind of issue?
Thanks

Comment: You will have to elaborate this question. How do the cookies look before you edit them, what exactly do you edit?

Comment: I am login into xyz.com, then edit its cookie using firebug and setting the pqr.com in domain field after that it allows me to logged in

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Zend framework, but this seems like a rather serious issue with their session management. I think you're better off directly contacting them (e.g. via their forum https://discourse.zendframework.com/)

Comment: @SaAtomic this issue is not related to zend this is happening misconfiguration in server or session management, I am sure there would be some other ways but I do not know.

Comment: If the framework doesn't handle sessions and you didn't mention anything else that does, I assume that you programmed the session management yourself. The applications apparently share the same session management, in which case you will have to add the domain, to allow distinct sessions between the two applications. Or implement session management per application.

Comment: so the issue is two applications are sharing their session, correct ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62389/discussion-between-ravi-and-saatomic).